# JS: Add link dynamically to all elements of certain class

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console

I work in a system where we have these elements representing a part of an audio clip, and a timeline for the audio that is browsable (click around to play different parts). However, the elements representing the parts of the audio clip does not actually link to the parts of the audio.. (so no "click this to play this part").

I have deducted that it is possible to link to a specific part of the call via for example: `http://thelink.com/timeline?startms=%221600326183999%22`. And that the elements all have an attribute called "startms", for example:

```
<div class="segment-item" startms="1600326183999"></div>
```

Is there any way I could loop through all the elements in the page with the class "segment-item" and add a href="" with the value of their individual "startms" value to the link (`http://thelink.com/timeline?startms=%22TheValueHere%22`).

Then finally, since I cannot build an addon to my browser for this, would it be possible to make a snipped which can be pasted into the console for easy use when I need it? Any other suggestions to making such a thing be easily accessible for usage without making or using an addon for chrome?

Comment: You can use `elem.querySelectorAll(css)`, which returns all elements inside elem matching the given CSS selector. Tampermonkey is a addon, which allows you to run custom js in your Browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the link to the element, you should add it like that

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("segment-item")
    for (element of elements) {
        const a = document.createElement("a")
        a.href = `http://thelink.com/timeline?startms=%22${element.getAttribute("startms")}%22`
        a.innerText = "LINK NAME"

        element.appendChild(a)
    }
```

Comment: you could also use the previous variation, but instead of assigning the link string to the innerHTML, you could do ` innerHTML += "<a href='.... " ` or  `innerHTML = "<a href='.... " + innerHTML`

Comment: This worked fine, but for some reason I'm not allowed to click the links. Suggestion on how to add the href to the div with segment-item class directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a link based on element properties goes like this

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("segment-item")
for (element of elements) {
    element.innerHTML = `<a href="http://thelink.com/timeline?startms=%22${element.getAttribute("startms")}%22">
                              Link name
                         </a>`
}
```

Comment: Hmm. No errors, but no effect either. Same when I tried to update it to this (which is what I want, as I don't want to change/replace the innerHTML of the DIV): `const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("segment-item")
for (element of elements) {
    element.setAttribute("href",\`http://thelink.com/timeline?startms=%22${element.getAttribute("startms")}%22\`);
}`

Comment: Wouldn't "this" be of use here somehow?